# update button query does not working properly mysql c#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-store-apps

I tried update the mysql database table using following button, but it doesn't work and it  will be passing catch and showing the error message inside catch.
But using the break point I saw values are passing to text box values

### Code

```
private void Button_Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            #region Variables
            string gender = null;
            if (isMale || isFemale)
            {
                gender = isMale ? "Male" : "Female";
            }
            string status = null;
            if (isSingle || isMarried)
            {
                status = isSingle ? "Single" : "Married";
            }
            string ol = null;
            if (isolYes || isolNo)
            {
                ol = isolYes ? "Yes" : "No";
            }
            string al = null;
            if (isalYes || isalNo)
            {
                al = isalYes ? "Yes" : "No";
            }
            string birth = null;
            if (isbirthYes || isbirthNo)
            {
                birth = isbirthYes ? "Yes" : "No";
            }
            string Nic = null;
            if (isNicYes || isNicNo)
            {
                Nic = isNicYes ? "Yes" : "No";
            }
            string police = null;
            if (ispoliceYes || ispoliceNo)
            {
                police = ispoliceYes ? "Yes" : "No";
            }

            string DoB = dobDateInput.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            string country = this.countryComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
            #endregion
            string Query = @"UPDATE `bcasdb`.`tbl_student`
                    SET
                   `reg_id` = '" + this.regIDInput.Text +
                "',`std_fname` = '" + this.fnameInput.Text +
                "',`std_lname` = '" + this.lnameInput.Text +
                "',`tbl_batch_batch_id` = '" + this.batchIDInput.Text +
                "',`gender` = '" + gender +
                "',`dob` = '" + DoB +
                "',`email` = '" + this.emailInput.Text +
                "',`mobile` = '" + this.mobileNoInput.Text +
                "',`contact_address` = '" + this.conAddressInput.Text +
                "',`home_address` = '" + this.homeAddressInput.Text +
                "',`status` = '" + status +
                "',`courceIDInput` = '" + this.courceIDInput.Text +
                "',`depart_id` = '" + this.depIDInput.Text +
                "',`parent_name` = '" + this.parentNameInput.Text +
                "',`nationality` = '" + country +
                "',`telephone` = '" + this.teleNoInput.Text +
                "',`nic` = '" + this.NICNoInput.Text +
                "',`passport_no` = '" + this.passportNoInput.Text +
                "',`acadamic_qulification` = '" + this.acdqlyInput.Text +
                "',`current_employement` = '" + this.currntEmpInput.Text +
                "',`gce_ol` = '" + ol +
                "',`gce_al` = '" + al +
                "',`birth_certifiacte` = '" + birth +
                "',`copy_of_nic` = '" + Nic +
                "',`police_clearance` = '" + police +
                "'  WHERE `reg_id` = '" + this.regIDInput.Text + "';";
            //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(BCASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader MyReader;
            conn.Open();
            MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();// this query will be executed and data saved into the database.           
            conn.Close();
            successmsgBox();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errormsgBox();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Never, never, NEVER write ADO.NET code like that.  Learn to use parameters to insert values into SQL code: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Comment: Also, why are you calling `ExecuteReader` when you're not reading anything?  Call `ExecuteNonQuery` for an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: this is windows store app and this is kind of project of me

Comment: On a general note, if an exception is thrown then actually look at it to see what the issue is.  That's why it's there.

Comment: I've never actually written a Store app myself so I'm not aware of what limitations there are but I find it hard to believe that they support ADO.NET but not the use of parameters and that they support `ExecuteReader` but not `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: show me your exact error message.

Comment: `{"Unknown column 'courceIDInput' in 'field list'"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to update data not fetching anything so try to use [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and always try to use [parametrized query](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx).

Your Code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(BCASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
int retval;
conn.Open();
retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// this query will be executed and data saved into the database.           
conn.Close();
successmsgBox();
```

*`Note: If retval == 1 then your database updated successfully else unsuccessful.`*